# Installing after build phantomjs 2.0 on linux

Tags: linux, node.js, installation, phantomjs

i followed the instructions here: http://phantomjs.org/build.html then i build it on linux (ubuntu), after this i get on this point "This produces a build bin/phantomjs. This is an executable; it can be moved to a different directory (e.g. /usr/local/bin) or another machine."

Yes it's there, an executable, but how i install it now? i tried using the commands phantomjs on terminal, i only had succes if i install it trough the command sudo apt-get install phantomjs or sudo npm install phantomjs

after this i run the code phantomjs -v and get the version: 1.9
i tried to run my code with phantomjs 1.9 but he ask's for 2.0
and i dont know how to install this exec file or use it to install the phantomjs 2.0, already tried to execute the file by double clicking, and using the command ./phantomjs on the directory... Also tried to run like windows, you go to directory which is the .exe file and then run the command normal like, phantomjs code.js but i doesn't work.

Sorry for this newbie question, im new with linux, starting using it this week.

Comment: [Making a script executable](http://superuser.com/questions/943607/making-a-script-executable)

Comment: Thanks, it solved for me